# Displaying suggested results in magento search with solr

Tags: magento, solr, full-text-search

I want to be able to display the results for the suggested search terms when a search on magento returns with no results but there are results for the suggested terms.

I want to be able to display the products for these search terms as if they were results of the original query.

This is using solr 3.6 and magento ee 1.13.0.2

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you have an idea how search works in Magento.

Once the keyword or phrase you submit gets processed by Magento, there will be two updates happening on the DB level; one on the search query table. And another on the search results table.

> catalogsearch_query
>
> catalogsearch_result

The idea is for Magento not to search again for the same term if that keyword or phrase was submitted by another customer to make the process faster in the future.

Solr:
Since you are already using it, there is two ways to go:

1. Make Solr be the search engine for the whole process, so you will be responsible for filling up the table with product IDs results, and if no products found then fill it up with suggested Products instead.
2. Let Magento handle the search with its mechanism,  and you can handle the case of no results by filling up the results table and updating the query table also from Solr.

In both cases, you will need to extend the functionality of the Magento catalog search module for this to work.